Token not coming - nextjs auth
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import dbConnect from '@/lib/dbConnect';
import UserModel from '@/model/User';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'credentials',
            name: 'Credentials',
            type: 'credentials',
            credentials: {
                email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
                password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
            },
            async authorize(credentials: any, req): Promise<any> {
                await dbConnect();
                try {
                    const user = await UserModel.findOne({
                        $or: [
                            { email: credentials.identifier },
                            { username: credentials.identifier },
                        ],
                    });
                    if (!user) {
                        throw new Error('No user found with this email');
                    }
                    if (!user.isVerified) {
                        throw new Error(
                            'Please verify your account before logging in'
                        );
                    }
                    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
                        credentials.password,
                        user.password
                    );
                    if (isPasswordCorrect) {
                        return user;
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Incorrect password');
                    }
                } catch (err: any) {
                    throw new Error(err);
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token._id = user._id?.toString();
                token.username = user.usernamQe;
                token.isVerified = user.isVerified;
                token.isAcceptingMessages = user.isAcceptingMessages;
            }

            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (token) {
                console.log(`token inside session: ${JSON.stringify(token)}`);
                session.user._id = token._id;
                session.user.isVerified = token.isVerified;
                session.user.isAcceptingMessages = token.isAcceptingMessages;
                session.user.username = token.username;
            }
            console.log(`session: ${JSON.stringify(session)}`);
            return session;
        },
    },
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt',
    },
    secret: 'sec3et',
    pages: {
        signIn: '/signin',
    },
};

it is options.ts where nextauth is doing its work but it is not giving jwt token to client side only session token is coming
Below code is middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const token = await getToken({ req: request });
    console.log('Token in middleware:', token);
    const url = request.nextUrl;

    if (
        token &&
        (url.pathname.startsWith('/signin') ||
            url.pathname.startsWith('/signup') ||
            url.pathname.startsWith('/verify') ||
            url.pathname.startsWith('/'))
    ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', request.url));
    }

    if (!token && url.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/signin', request.url));
    }
}

export const config = {
    matcher: ['/', '/signin', '/signup', '/dashboard/:path*', '/verify/:path*'],
};

token is not coming only next-auth-session is present
I want that when user signin i want to redirect to /dashboard   frontend is working proper but only token is not coming
